# Possibilities of different numbers adding up to an integer

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < n_4 < n_5$ be positive integers such that
>   $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 + n_5 = 20$.  Then the number of such distinct arrangements $(n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5)$ is

*My attempt*
First thing is that one would not be able to use stars and bars technique as the numbers cannot be equal.
Hence I tried to count all the cases up to 20 which gave the answer as $7$ possibilities.

[image: I found out the following]

$$n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 + n_5 = k$$

Or

$$n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 + n_5 + n_6 + n_7 + \ldots + n_j = k$$

However , generalising it for an integer $k$ , counting each time would be tedious if $k$ is large.  I was hoping someone could suggest an alternate way to solve such problems ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Do you have exaclty 7? I find (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5) = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10), (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5) = (1, 2, 3, 5, 9), (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5) = (1, 2, 3, 6, 8), (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5) = (1, 2, 4, 5, 8) using summation max of n5 = 10. min of up to n3 = 6 (n1, n2, n3) = (1, 2, 3)

Comment: @kimiTanaka see the possibilities in edit

Answer (score 0):

See http://oeis.org/A008289 for a general formula. The second formula listed there gives a simple recursion that can be used to compute larger values.